# Domains to normalize must have a 'domain' form: a list or tuple of domain components - Odoov10 community migration

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

I have this method:

```
@api.multi
def _get_url(self):
    """ Get seniat web page
    """
    url = self.env['seniat.url']
    url_ids = url.search('seniat.url')
    if len(url_ids) > 1:
        url.unlink.self.env.url_ids[1:] 
    url_obj = self.env['url_ids'].browse() 
    return url_obj 

@api.multi
def _get_url1(self): 
    url_obj = self._get_url() 
    return url_obj.name


@api.multi
def _get_url2(self): 
    url_obj = self._get_url() 
    return url_obj.url_seniat

@api.multi
def _get_url3(self): 
    url_obj = self._get_url() 
    return url_obj.url_seniat2
```

Every time I click on this it throws me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 675, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 331, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/service/model.py", line 119, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 324, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 933, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 504, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 862, in call_kw
return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 854, in _call_kw
return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 679, in call_kw
return call_kw_model(method, model, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 664, in call_kw_model
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 1101, in default_get
defaults[name] = field.default(self)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/gilda/l10n_ve_fiscal_requirements/wizard/wizard_url_seniat.py", line 41, in <lambda>
default=lambda s: s._get_url3(),
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/gilda/l10n_ve_fiscal_requirements/wizard/wizard_url_seniat.py", line 69, in _get_url3
url_obj = self._get_url() 
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/gilda/l10n_ve_fiscal_requirements/wizard/wizard_url_seniat.py", line 50, in _get_url
url_ids = url.search('seniat.url') 
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 1497, in search
res = self._search(args, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order, count=count)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 4185, in _search
query = self._where_calc(args)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 3984, in _where_calc
e = expression.expression(domain, self)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/osv/expression.py", line 640, in __init__
self.expression = distribute_not(normalize_domain(domain))
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/osv/expression.py", line 189, in normalize_domain
assert isinstance(domain, (list, tuple)), "Domains to normalize must have a 'domain' form: a list or tuple of domain components"
AssertionError: Domains to normalize must have a 'domain' form: a list or tuple of domain components
```

I'm really stuck on this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have checked your code. The problem is in the **_get_url** method.

```
@api.multi
def _get_url(self):
    """ Get seniat web page
    """
    url = self.env['seniat.url']
    #url_ids = url.search('seniat.url') **this is wrong syntax of search method**
    url_ids = url.search([]) # Here you need to give domain in list of tuple
    if len(url_ids) > 1:
        url.unlink.self.env.url_ids[1:] 
    url_obj = self.env['url_ids'].browse() 
    return url_obj
```

Thanks